# Save Name of Reference Workbook as Value

Tags: excel, vba

The macro below is designed to compile data from an audit form used throughout my organization.
Each manager saves their audit in a separate workbook monthly--I modify the If-Then statement frequently, dependent upon what data points I am investigating.

In the example below, the "F2" and "F3" range signify the manager, and date for each audit, so the output may look something like this:

- Manager A | Jan 1 | data point 1
- Manager A | Jan 1 | data point 2
- Manager A | Jan 1 | data point 3
- Manager B | Jan 2 | data point 1
- Manager B | Jan 2 | data point 2
- Manager B | Jan 2 | data point 3

etc.

Because these fields require manual entry, I've been experiencing some issues attributed to human error.  I'd like to add a column that records the name of the workbook being referenced, so that I can more easily deep dive these issues.

I know the destination:
WS.Range("A" & Lrow & ":A" & Lrow + 2)

But I can't quite figure out how to save the file name for each Active Workbook in the loop.  Any suggestions?

---

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim myfolder As String
Dim Str As String
Dim a As Single
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set WS = Sheets.Add

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Show
    myfolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

Value = Dir(myfolder)
Do Until Value = ""
    If Value = "." Or Value = ".." Then
    Else
        If Right(Value, 3) = "xls" Or Right(Value, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(Value, 4) = "xlsm" Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=myfolder & Value, Password:="zzzzzzzzzzzz"
            If Err.Number > 0 Then
            Else
                On Error GoTo 0
            For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                    If sht.Name Like "CQI" Then
                        Lrow = WS.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                        sht.Range("F2").Copy
                        WS.Range("B" & Lrow & ":B" & Lrow + 2).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
                        sht.Range("F3").Copy
                        WS.Range("C" & Lrow & ":C" & Lrow + 2).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
                        sht.Range("F54:F56").Copy
                        WS.Range("D" & Lrow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
                        sht.Range("C54:E56").Copy
                        WS.Range("E" & Lrow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

                    End If
                Next sht
            End If


            End If
            Workbooks(Value).Close False
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Value = Dir
Loop
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Name`? Or just `Value`?

Comment: -I must have been spacing, lol!  Thanks for the help, 
WS.Range("A" & Lrow & ":A" & Lrow + 8).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Name worked perfectly!